# Play framework web application: when to use Akka?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm transitioning from Java to Scala, and started using Play as application server. My Java legacy application (the one I'm trying to replace) is built on three layers: servlets, session beans and entity beans. I read that Akka actors would replace session beans, is that accurate? When is it appropriate to use Akka actors in a Play web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any thumb rule like convert Session Beans / Entity Beans to actors.

You may need to look at your requirements. It's worth considering what the actor model is used for: the actor model is

- a concurrency model that avoids concurrent access to mutable state
- using asynchronous communications mechanisms to provide concurrency

This is valuable because using shared state from multiple threads gets really hard, especially when there are relationships among different components of the shared state that must be kept synchronized.

However, if you have domain components in which:
You don't allow concurrency, OR
You don't allow mutable state (as in functional programming), OR
You must rely on some synchronous communications mechanism,
then the actor model will not provide much (if any) benefit.

Take a look at this URL if you haven't already http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/02/akka-ejbs-concurrency

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of the question:

> When is it appropriate to use Akka actors in a Play web application?

Scala is not just syntactical sugared Java but meant to write Functional Programming(FP). Scala makes writing functional code easier and more obvious. When you do this all your methods become functions(no state change is held).

From here when you do want to hold global state, you encapsulate it within an Actor and interact with it only via a messaging queue.. and therefore don't have to concern yourself with threading logic.

A great course to get started with this is https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun

A great book to get started with Scala is:
Scala for the Impatient by Cay S. Horstmann

Comment: What do you meain by `global state`? A singleton?

Comment: Usually you might have global state in your app. It might be a singleton or some long task that you are trying to process. For ex. You want to upload a video so you might break it up into smaller pieces and do it in parallel. The video would be state in your app for the duration of the upload task.

Comment: You are trying to explain need for functional programming. Note Play and AKKA both are on Java as well. So the question is more on when to use AKKA Actors.